# Unexpected token with es6 map in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this in jsx where is an array like `breadcrumb = ['food','hotdogt']` but I got an error of `unexpected token .`?

```
{breadcrumb.map(obj => {
   {obj}
})}
```

Comment: Try to save the result of the `map` function to a variable and put the variable into the render instead of your previous approach.

Comment: @JDHrnnts I did that in jsbin.

Comment: Can you post a link to that resource?

Comment: *"es6 map"*  - `.map()` isn't an ES6 function.

Comment: No value is returned from `.map()` at `javascript` at Question, the result would be `[undefined, undefined]`

Comment: sounds like your code isn't being transpiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
{
    breadcrumb.map(obj => {
         return <div> {obj} </div>
    })
}
```

or

```
{
   breadcrumb.map(obj => <div> {obj} </div>)
}
```

or

```
{
   breadcrumb.map(obj => obj)
}
```

`{}` braces are required when you are using `js` code inside `html` element, you are using `{obj}` but didn't use any `html` element. And you forgot to use `return` also.

Check this example:

```js
var breadcrumb = ['food','hotdogt'];

var App = () => {
   return(
       <div>
          {
             breadcrumb.map(obj => <p key={obj}> {obj} </p>)
          }
          {
             breadcrumb.map((obj, i) => { 
                return <span key={obj}>
                           <span className="bold"> {obj} </span> 
                           {i != breadcrumb.length -1 ? <span className="seperator"> -> </span> : null} 
                       </span>
             })
          }
       </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: thanks but I'm stuck with html within jsx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153114/simple-breadcrum-logo-in-jsx-of-react-binding

Comment: you want the result like this: a->b->c->d->e ?? if a,b,c,d,e will be the items of the array.

Comment: correct but I messed up with the html tag within jsx, I messed up with the concatenation. The `->` should be wrapped within tag so that I can style them.

Comment: I can't make the item has current style because everything is within one span, that's a problem.

Comment: check the updated answer, let me know if you need any other help :)