# Simple breadcrum logo in jsx of react binding

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{breadcrumbs.map((obj,i) => 
    <p> {i} > 1 ? "<span className="seperator">|</span>" : <span className="bold">{obj}</span> </p>
)}
```

I want to make breadcrumbs from an array but failed using above code. `breadcrumbs` is just an array ['books','javascript'] and my expected output will be

Books -> javascript and so on, it should be working if I have more than 2 item in the array.

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear about what you expect to see here.  Give an example that includes more than two array elements with a clearer example of the html that you want to see produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this:

```js
var breadcrumb = ['food','hotdogt', 'a', 'b', 'c'];

var App = () => {
   return(
       <div>
          {
             breadcrumb.map((obj,i) => {
                return <span key={obj}>
                           <span className="bold"> {obj} </span>
                           {i != breadcrumb.length -1 ? <span className="seperator"> -> </span> : null} 
                       </span>
             })
          }
       </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.seperator {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: very straight forward, index is not needed, I'm over thinking, thanks for this!

Comment: Wait, there's important stuff missing here. I can't style the item without wrapping them inside html tag and give them classname

Comment: i represent the index of item, we need to avoid the arrow `->` when i reaches to last element, for that we need to check `i != length`, if you use `i!=0` it will not render first `->` and there will be an extra `->` after the last element, just replace that condition by `i!=0`, and check the output, it will be something like this: `a b -> c -> d -> e ->`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in the syntax, as I'm not a React user, but the base logic is bad. If you doing a breadcrumb, you should put separators between the entries except the last one. Based on **HJ Cross**'s answer, here is the correct code you looking for:

```
var arry = ['books','javascript', 'reactJS'];
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {arry.map((obj,i) => 
      <p key={i}><span className="bold">{obj}</span>{
        i < arry.length - 1 
          ?  <span className="seperator">-&gt;</span>
          : <span className="none"></span>
      }</p>
    )}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with this code is with syntax.  Curly braces are placed improperly and elements should not be strings, ie. the spans.

The other issue is how you are trying to handle separators and their classes.  You need to insert a separator before all elements except the first. One way to do this is with a reduce that modifies the array before you map it.

A side point, place a key on all mapped items.

Here's what it looks like working:

```
  <p>
    {['books','javascript'].reduce((all, one, i) => {
        i > 0 && all.push('->');
        all.push(one);
        return all;
    }, []).map((obj, i) => 
      <span key={i} className={i%2 ? 'seperator' : 'bold'}>{obj}</span>
    )}
  </p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q0vt53po/1/

Comment: where's the seperator in ur jsfiddle? I want book -> javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function to render the conditional components like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  conditionalRender(i, len) {
   if (i < len -1) 
   return <span className="seperator">-></span> 
   
  }
  render() {
  
    var breadcrumbs = ['books','javascript', 'something'];
    
    return (
         <div>{breadcrumbs.map((obj,i) => 
              <span><span className="bold"> {obj} </span>{this.conditionalRender(i, breadcrumbs.length)} </span>
          )}</div>
    )
  }
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```